# Find a user defined keyword in real-time log (text) file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am running a process in linux which logs the status and others info in a log file `/home/path/Detail_File.log` in text format. the file is being continuously written using a background process. I can display the file contents using `tail -f /home/path/Detail_File.log`.

I want to check the file for a key word **`keyword`** (say). How do I continuously check if the key word is found, and if found get that line in a variable.

I am not sure what should I search on internet so posting this question directly without the primary research. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:** Adding screenshot of the while loop  suggestion by @jhnc
[image]

The `echo "Time elapsed: $curr_time ..."` is executed and then its silent

Comment: `tail -f` is not the same as `tail -n +1 -f`. If you find a matching line in less than 2 minutes, you abort the `while` loop with `break` so why would you expect more output after that?

Comment: `$(($curr_time))` is a complicated way to get `$curr_time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GNU utilities, `grep` has a `--line-buffered` option:

```
tail -n +1 -f /home/path/Detail_File.log |\
grep --line-buffered -F keyword |\
while read matchedline; do
    dosomething "$matchedline"
done
```

This is a pipeline: `cmd1 | cmd1 | cmd3`

Backslash (`\`) at end of line allows using linebreak for readability.

- `tail` output is fed into `grep`.
- `grep` output is fed into the `while` loop.
- `read` gets its input from `grep`, not from the user.

Usually, `grep` output is buffered - the output only becomes available once the pipe buffer is full. The `--line-buffered` option causes the pipe buffer to be flushed after every line. For example, consider difference between output of:

```
while sleep 1; do date; done |\
grep --line-buffered . |\
while read line; do echo "$(date) :: $line"; done |\
head
```

versus (may take a few minutes before you see anything):

```
while sleep 1; do date; done |\
grep . |\
while read line; do echo "$(date) :: $line"; done |\
head
```

Comment: Yes I am using GNU. Can you tell me how does this work? Is `read matchedline` expecting user input with each iteration?

Comment: It is working! but I am not able to terminate the **while** loop `while read x; do if [ x == a ]; then break; done` can you tell why?

Comment: because "x" is not equal to "a" ?

Comment: I have edited the question with the snapshot of what I am trying.